# substitute for \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid) in Drupal 8.9

Tags: 8

My goal is to load a file and get its properties.

The method 'Load' does not exist any more in Drupal 8.9 (in the File.php file)

`\Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid);`

What would be the substitute for this function?

I'm using <theme_name>*preprocess_views*<field_name> hook to override the output of a view.
From here I'm able to retrieve the file id by using

`$fid = $variables['field']->getValue($variables['row'])[0];`

With the file id, my plan is to load the file and retrieve all its properties, such as label, uri, etc.

Searched the web and all recommendations are to use
`\Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid);`

however, this method no longer exists Drupal 8.9

How would I go to load this file and get its properties??

Thanks!

Comment: It hasn't changed. load() was never in File.php but in one of the base classes. All entities in Drupal support the load() method.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. 
Thanks @Clive!
Using '$storage' worked! 
Tried making as the correct answer, but I don't have enough points to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All entity types, of which `\Drupal\file\Entity\File` is one, have a static `load()` method. This comes from [`EntityBase::load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityBase.php/function/EntityBase%3A%3Aload/9.2.x), and is present throughout all versions of Drupal 8 and 9.

You can keep using that method, it's not going anywhere, but alternatively you can use the entity type manager service, e.g.

```
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('file');
$file = $storage->load($fid);
```

Note that the service should be injected if your code is in a context which allows it.